# twitter bootstrap modal does not work in rails3 layout?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, modal-dialog

I have a twitter bootstrap modal dialog.  I used the example here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

and this works well by its self.  Works well if I add this to a rails view like index.html.erb of one of my views.  Though if I add the same stuff that works to my layout (specifically my navigation one) so that this modal can come down on ANY view in the app, while it works, it never "fades in" it is always behind a darkened screen.  I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this is.  I can literally take the modal div, slap it into the view and it works fine, if its in that layout though.  No dice.  I am not sure what I am missing or if this is just a bug in twitter boot strap modals or what?  Anyone else have this issue?  Am I missing something to add to the class of the modal?