# Am I misusing Ruby on Rails Layouts

Tags: ruby, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

EDIT:

Okay, so using cells I have got it running, indeed the rb file created by the cells scripted needed:

```
helper ApplicationHelper
```

this got past the error in the comments below, but now inside my application helper, i have a method:

```
  def hr_user_past
    @current_year = current_year
    @hr_user_past ||= Employee.where("username=? and year < ?", session[:hr_user].username, @current_year).order("Year DESC") if session[:hr_user]
    @past_times = @current_year - 2011
    @blart = 'test'
  end
```

And alas, this now cannot find `current_year` which is a def method in my application_controller.rb, so I think my flow is all messed up and not sure what I need to have where for a good solid "include".

Def of the current_year from application controller

```
 class ApplicationController < Actioncontroller::Base

            helper_method :current_year

  ... 
  ...
      def   current_year

         OpenPeriod.maximum :year
      end
 end
```

I also am worried all this work still wont solve the issue I am having with the twitter bootstrap modal dialog being called from a layout and not fadeing in all the way with data (minute i put the same code in a view, it works right)... but one issue at a time i guess...

*END EDIT*

Trying to have an objective question here though.  Some background:

I have a navigation layout that has this nice login, home button and a few others on it.  It works fine, lately the customer wanted some more functionality added to this namely a smart button that drops down dynamically with data filled out (stuff from years past from old forms we use).

So the app used a twitter bootstrap modal elsewhere.  I just posted this question here:

[twitter bootstrap modal does not work in rails3 layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629893/twitter-bootstrap-modal-does-not-work-in-rails3-layout)

Where I am having an issue with this modal working correctly from the layout.  Then I got to thinking, this modal that drops down has some good amount of data usually from a specific controller, but they want to see this data at any moment.  Is the layout way of doing this not the way, should I build an application helper .rb code to fill out a partial and include that partial on every page in the app? ( seeems like it should fix my modal displaying oddly, like constantly faded issue).  I think my green-ness to ruby on rails is at fault here.  I know its awesome and there is a lot to it and this is the first project I have done in it.  So I am not sure what the correct solution is here, and I think its a vocabulary issue.  Like what am i looking for?

Form helpers
Templates
Partials
etc etc... what is the best fit here?  I realize in coding there is a lot of ways to skin a cat but I am not sure where to ask.  Rereading this is getting subjective.  Basically

I have a home controller that sets up things on a home page, turns out this data needs to be seen by the user at any given moment from any page in the app.  Tried to move it to our navigation layout, its not going well.  Is this the right approach or is there a better one?

Comment: Why is `current_year` a helper method in your `ApplicationController` and not just a method in your `ApplicationHelper`? If you moved it there, it would work.

Comment: you are right. and that worked, I didn't write stuff originally so trying to jam it all in.   Though I am back to my original issue in that for some reason that twitter bootstrap modal does not work being called from a layout, it shows up works, but fades out the screen and shows up "behind" the fade.  SOOo bizzare.   Oh well at least I have things setup mostly correctly.  thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a purely html/css issue. Probably a z-index getting set somewhere, or the divs end up in the wrong order.

Comment: thanks for the hint, some more googling did indeed show that there are issues with the z-index when that model is done multiple times in specific ways on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/). Essentially, a cell is a miniature controller that takes care of fetching data and rendering a view. It's not quite a full-blown view, it's a component which, similar to a partial, may be included into other views of your application - or even the layout, which is useful when you have something that appears on every page.

A classic example (which they implement on their homepage) is that of a shopping cart - it appears throughout your app but it needs to have some data set; turning it into a cell extracts both the querying and the rendering into a nicely-separated MVC unit.

Comment: okay i will investigate this.  I have not yet heard of these.  Thanks Andy!  One final question on Cells, looks like I would still have to call the cells from every page, correct?  like I cannot include it in my navigation layout.  Particularly because well it seems to not work well with the twitter-bootstrap modal. Thats what i would have the cell in, is the modal-dialog bootstrap div.

Comment: You can definitely put cells in layouts. See the section titled "Plug in!" on the homepage.

Comment: Darn.  this was close, got the gem implemented it and got an error on an application_helper .rb method i have `def is_past?`  it says undefined method.  I am not sure why.  I had another error (went away after restarting webrick though about it not finding the render_cell)  still not sure what I am doing wrong here... feels like im close though

Comment: Are you trying to use `is_past?` in your cell? I'm not sure that it automatically includes your helpers... see [here](https://github.com/apotonick/cells#helpers) - you might have to put `helper ApplicationHelper` in there.

Comment: I edited the original question with updates here, still not working.  Please see edit.